# How to triger a click handler after $.post has added a button dynamically in jquery

Tags: html, css, jquery

I have a requirement where i'm dynamically generating some rows and each row has a button and an id associated with it and i do this using $.post() of jQuery. And this content is periodically refreshed.

A problem has occurred due to this... After $.post has finished its execution, the buttons are not triggering the click event... How do i correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's .on() method to listen for events on dynamically added DOM elements:

```
$("body").on("click", ".dynamic_elem", function(){
  console.log( $(this) );
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

EDIT:: Make sure you are using jQuery 1.7+. For the older versions, you can try .live() and .delegate().

Comment: Post your HTML and Javascript.

Comment: yep... just a min i'll post a fiddle

Comment: echo '<td><input type="submit" id="'.$res['id'].'" value ="Start" class="clickButton" /></td>'

Comment: Please say you're not using jQuery 1.3.2? If so there is no `on()` method.

Comment: Seems to work for me -> [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m3P8S/1/), make sure you type everything correct, and watch out for case on classes.

Comment: it works if i hard code the button there... but when i get it via $.post, its not working

Comment: Are you sure it has the same class.

Comment: yep... its the same... i ussually copy paste it... u can see it on my fiddle

Comment: Well, no I can't! There's no way for us to see what your ajax function returns ?

Comment: ok no problem... i'm doing it inline and for now, its working!!! need to get the site up and running by tonight... anyways thank you very much for your concern...

Comment: whoa sorry i missed the thread. yeah make sure you're using 1.7+

Comment: You're welcome, and since this most likely is the correct answer, give it a upvote.